# Fiji: How can I use the information of the image in order to set the scale?

Tags: imagej

the images created in the microscope that we use in our lab don't have a scale bar. Can i use the information stored at the image itself/information from the microscope itself, in order to properly set the scale, and convert pixels into nm?
I've downloaded the plugin called "microscope scale", but I don't understand how to use it.
thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Reading the description of the [Microscope Scale plugin](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/microscope-scale.html) it sounds like you would need to manually edit the plugin's source code to set the scale for your data.

Instead I would suggest using the [Bio-Formats Importer](http://fiji.sc/Bio-Formats#Bio-Formats_Importer) to open your data, as it has a good chance of reading calibration values directly from your images (if they were saved by the microscope).

If Bio-Formats doesn't work, then you can manually set the scale using the [Spatial Calibration plugin](http://fiji.sc/SpatialCalibration) provided with Fiji to convert pixels to nm.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer!! I will look it all up.

Comment: Hello hinerm and everybody, I did tried the Bio-Formats Importer plugin but still, there is an inconsistency between the length values as showed at the early window of "All paths", and the later window (opened after performing the "analyse skeleton"). Wish I could add a picture, I hope I'm clear.

Comment: If the calibration information wasn't correct when opening with Bio-Formats, it probably isn't written into the metadata of your image (or is written incorrectly). If you know what the calibration data values are supposed to be, try using the `Set Scale...` command in the `Analyze` menu. If that doesn't work you might have better luck mailing the ImageJ mailing list (http://imagej.net/Mailing_Lists)